# How do I transform this: [['2', '3', '1', '7']] into the number [23.17] in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list `[['2', '3', '1', '7']]` and I would like to assemble these numbers into the number 23.17 (float). It seems simple but I'm having trouble to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a list of lists, rather than a simple list. If you know that you are always trying to have 2 decimal places, what you can do is join all the elements in each list, convert to `int` or `float`, and divide by 100. If you convert to `int`, it will automatically become float when you divide.

```
l = [['2', '3', '1', '7']]

>>> [int(''.join(i)) / 100 for i in l]
[23.17]
```